# Open file created by C# DeflateStream in Windows

Tags: c#, compression

I am debugging some data (JSON string) that is being sent to a PHP API that has been compressed in C# using `DeflateStream`:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream())){
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
    byteArray = Compress(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(incomingData)));
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"compressed-"+ randomNumber + ".gz", byteArray);
}
```

Here is the definition for `Compress()`

```
private static byte[] Compress(Stream input)
        {
            using (var compressStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                input.CopyTo(compressor);
                compressor.Close();
                return compressStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to open this file that has been created in Windows? I tried 7zip and Winrar to no avail. If I were to use `GZipStream` I can open it, but PHP isn't compatible with that format.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't write header information and metadata so you can't 'open' it like a zip file... You could always simply perform the reverse (i.e. Decompress with a DeflateStream) to get the original data...

Comment: How would I add that header info? I wouldn't need it long term, but it would be nice to extend what I have instead of build a new application to open compressed strings.